# CVP to SVP reduction?

Tags: np, integer-lattice

The notes here provide a reduction from $SVP$ to $CVP$ https://people.csail.mit.edu/vinodv/COURSES/CSC2414-F11/L4.pdf.

Is there a reduction in the reverse direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "yes," but with several caveats, maybe the most important of which is that all known such reductions from CVP to SVP in the Euclidean norm are randomized. Self promotion: check out Section 3 of [my survey on SVP](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2022/170/).

Comment: I see only a reduction from GapCVP using Kannan's embedding but not from CVP to SVP.

Comment: The reductions described there are between the decision (Gap) versions of the problems (and in fact from a variant of GapCVP), but also works for the search versions. (Kannan's embedding isn't a valid reduction by itself.)

Comment: Perhaps I am new to the area and so I don't know. Isn't CVP different from GapCVP?

Comment: "Gap" just means the decision version. This is explained in the introduction!